Why the Form doesnt load the values?
I'm currently building a Create Account page for my project and trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. The issue is that, when I fill in all the blanks and press the Create Account button it sends empty values. I have no idea why is that.. I hope someone here will help me. Thanks!
@page "/CreateAccount"

@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using WebApp.Models

@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Create Account</PageTitle>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100 bg-dark text-white">
    <EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="RegisterAccount" class="text-center w-25" FormName="CreateAccount">
        <h1 class="mb-5">Create an Account</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="user.Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <InputText id="email" @bind-Value="user.Email" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <InputText id="password" @bind-Value="user.Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
        </div> 

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Create Account</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private AccountDetails user = new AccountDetails();

    private async Task RegisterAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Email: {user.Email}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Username: {user.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Password: {user.Password}");

        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("ApiClient");
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/AccountDetails", user);
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/HomeManager");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}

Model
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class AccountDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 6 characters long")]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

API
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AccountDetailsContext _context;

        public AccountDetailsController(AccountDetailsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAccountDetails([FromBody] AccountDetails accountDetails)
        {
            if (accountDetails == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received null data.");
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Received data: Name={accountDetails.Name}, Email={accountDetails.Email}, Password={accountDetails.Password}");

            try
            {
                _context.AccountDetails.Add(accountDetails);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried HTTP Post method directly in Visual Studio by REST Client extension and the data are saved fine into database. Only, when the user enters the values in the form it sends empty values
POST http://localhost:5237/api/AccountDetails
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "Name": "User",
  "Email": "user@gmail.com",
  "Password": "12345",
  "CreatedAt": "2005-07-21"
}


it should be like @bind-Value=@user.Name

Nope, same issue

Your code worked on my end, it's posting the values. Can you try adding a breakpoint to var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/AccountDetails", user); and see if it's attempting to send a user object with values?

Also add a breakpoint to your controller, is it really reaching PostAccountDetails?

Added breakpoint to var response and everything empty (email, name, password).

@kelq Are those really all your code for CreateAccount page? I copied your code and it is capturing the values and sending properly on my end.

Be sure add [SupplyParameterFromForm] and change user to property instead of field like below. The [SupplyParameterFromForm] attribute indicates that the value of the associated property should be supplied from the form data :
[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private AccountDetails user { get; set; } = new AccountDetails();

UPDATE:
You can also set the render mode by adding the following code to the CreateAccount component:
@page "/CreateAccount"
@rendermode InteractiveServer


What type of rendering mode is it?
You may have to add
@rendermode="InteractiveServer"

if it is not set to Interactive mode globally.
